# Why is getEntityManager() not defined? "Cannot resolve method getEntityManager"

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am building an android app that integrates with google appengine datastore without using JDO.

I am trying to build an endpoint that will allow me to access the data in my datastore.  The function I am writing is below, but I am having an odd problem, despite putting this code into the endpoints java class...

The error I get is `Cannot Resolve Method getEntityManager()`

In every example that I see online, it all calls this function. -- so there must be a way to make it work, or I must be doing something silly.

What am I missing?  How can I resolve this

```
@Api(name = "getPostsApi", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "endpoints.myModule.myCo.com",
        ownerName = "endpoints.myModule.myCo.com", packagePath=""))
public class GetPostsEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
    @ApiMethod(name = "GetPostsEndpoint")
    public CollectionResponse<NewPostBean> listStuff(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {


        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<NewPostBean> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();   // <---- Breaks on this line

            //Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Stuff as Stuff");
//                limit =1;

            //execute = (List<NewPostBean>) query.getResultList();
            //cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            //for (NewPostBean obj : execute)
            //    ;
        //} finally {
         //   mgr.close();
        //}

        return CollectionResponse.<NewPostBean>builder().setItems(execute).setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview#Getting_an_EntityManager_Instance), I see that they actually get the Entity manager by creating this class:

```
public final class EMF {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMF() {}

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }
}
```

THEN they call EMF.get() to get the Entity Manager. I used just that and it works. What code did you find that calls "getEntityManager" out of the blue like that? getEntityManager doesn't seem defined at all according to the code you posted

Comment: I was following a tutorial online!  I guess they left that part out.  Also, I added a variable and a function to return the EntityManager instead of the EntityManagerFactory.  thanks a lot

Comment: Very welcome :) surprising a tutorial left such an important part out :P